# Vertically align span within a (link) tag within list element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align a menu button I've made using `span` tags next to a `text field` I've made. I would like to do it without applying a fixed margin to the top if possible.

Here is an example of the code I've written:
https://jsfiddle.net/dLbdxa4j/3/

What am I doing wrong?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.line {
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" value="Search me!" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `inline-block` on the `li`'s with `vertical-align` or make the parent `flex` and use `align-items` to align them vertically. Also make the `a` `inline-block` so it's centered properly taking into consideration the vertical margin on `.line`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.inlineBlock li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Search me!" />
  </li>
</ul>



<ul class="inlineBlock">
  <li>
    <a>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="text" value="Search me!" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is edit the css for list-items and the '.line' class:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.line {
    width: 22px;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/81sdqfak/2/)

If you want to do it strictly through floating, then add the following rule to your css:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

You can also add a new class to the list-item with the search-field in it so that you don't have to depend on html hierarchy.

[Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/81sdqfak/3/)

Comment: margin-top : 5px is average, if you reset font-size or use another font, it can break, with em unit , it would be a little breakless ;) ( display has other possibilities: table-cell, flex, inline-flex, inline-table ... inline-block should be just fine :)